# Should 404 response include body

Tags: rest, api-design

I wanted to know what fellow developers follow while designing rest API error responses.

For all the not-found  `get` resources, do you also send the some sort of body indicating that resource was not found or some more detailed level error messages or only error code with `null` or `blank` response?

Comment: What would you put in the body?

Comment: Exactly, that was my thought as well. Some fellow devs in my organization send custom json like `{ "code": 404, "details": "Customer not found" }` which I think does not make sense.

Comment: Unless that information makes it onto the UI or into a log somewhere, I don't think it adds any value.

Comment: If I try to get information about a customer, and I get a 404, in which way would be "details": "Customer not found" be helpful to me? I know already that the customer was not found.

Comment: An example of it being done and another example making it a necessity: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/handle-errors
https://services.expediapartnercentral.com/products/documentation/api/errors

Comment: The expedia example doesn't provide any information with 404's that the caller wouldn't have known.

Comment: keep it simple and send a response body. Developers will appreciate it. If you still think that your system is going to be candy for hackers because it's the most important application on Earth, visit the API of more modest companies like Google, Facebook. No surprises if you see response bodies there, it's like they have never evaluated the risk and vulnerabilities of saying something like "resource not found".

Answer (score 23):

> For all the not-found get resources, do you also send the some sort of body indicating that resource was not found or some more detailed level error messages or only error code with null or blank response?

Safety first!

The first thing to consider is: can an attacker use that information for anything, including crafting better attacks in the future?

I often tell the cautionary tale of an exception in a pre-release version of .NET where the exception error message was basically "`You don't have permission to know the name of directory C:\foo`". That's a very helpful error message, but it defeats the purpose of hiding the secret from low-trust code. (This problem was caught and fixed before any version of .NET shipped to customers.)

In particular be careful of error messages that distinguish between "that doesn't exist" and "that exists but you can't see it". It is often a good idea to simply never return a 403 "forbidden" error and instead always return 404 "not found".

If your diagnostics allow an attacker to distinguish between forbidden and not found, they can use that difference to gradually enumerate the space of possibly-existing resources to determine which do and do not exist.

I introduced exactly this vulnerability into VBScript in the 1990s; an attacker could write a web page that gradually learned your machine's directory structure by checking error messages that made this distinction. They could not read files, but they could determine the names of files and directories by trial and error.

Thus, a good practice for web-based APIs is to **fail to the secure mode**: say as little as possible in an error message unless you know the client to be authenticated and trusted to have **all** the information in the error message.

Comment: In case of a hypothetical REST API I would assume some sort of authentication is in place

Comment: REST doesn't need to be authenticated. In fact, authenticated REST is a special beast because you have to do special authentication that maintains RESTfulness. That is a completely separate problem, but we should always code the error to default to the lowest security, then do special processing for authenticated errors.

Comment: @Nelson, not sure what you are trying to say, but if a client is not authenticated / authorized you _always_ tell them they are not authenticated / authorized giving no other information, like a 404.

Comment: So basically never ever send a response body alongside with 4xx or 5xx errors. A non-sense. Sorry but I disagree with this reasoning. It just takes me a 1 valid URI to guess whether the URI+1 i'm testing "does not exist" or if it's resources "is not found". And a valid authorization of course.

Comment: @Laiv: Think bigger than just checking URLs. For example: suppose I want to find out if a user with email `foo@bar.com` has an account on a service, because I believe that this user can be phished. I send that user id and a blank password to the service. If I get a different error message for "no such user" and "wrong password" then I can know whether that user is a good phishing target for that service. Or, given a corpus of a few million known email addresses, I can gradually enumerate which of them are members of the service.

Comment: @Laiv: This attack pattern is generally applicable to a great many sorts of resources, but the people who write error messages are thinking from the perspective of the engineers who have to diagnose the failures, not from the perspective of attackers who wish to do harm to users. When you write an error message of any sort, think about who is getting the error and what use they are putting it to.

Comment: +1 for the nice excample with the .Net error message

Answer (score 19):

> The [4xx (Client Error)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5) class of status code indicates that the client seems to have erred.  Except when responding to a HEAD request, the server SHOULD send a representation containing an explanation of the error situation, and whether it is a temporary or permanent condition.

[404](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.4) is, of course, a status code of the 4xx class, therefore the body of the response should (in the [RFC 2119 sense](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2119#section-3)) include a message body.

Because the response includes a 4xx status code, general purpose components will know (a) that the included representation is that of an error, and not the resource itself (b) will know whether or not the error representation is cacheable (in the case of 404, by default the representation may be cached).

[RFC 7807](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7807) describes `application/problem+json`, a media type designed for general purpose communication of errors.

Comment: This answer should be Accepted.

Answer (score 9):

It is very common for 404 responses to contain content in the body.  The first example would be when you go to web sites, you get a helpful HTML page that has links to go back or go to the front page.

There is no reason why an API call shouldn't return a response body.  In fact, it's something that the [JSON:API specification](https://jsonapi.org/format/#errors) encourages.  The main reason is that it simplifies the error handling code on the client side if your server always returns content.

On the other hand, if you are not using the JSON:API standard, then you can make your own informed decision on the matter.  The HTTP Status code does provide sufficient information for the client to know the resource does not exist.  The only downside is that error handling in the client *may* be slightly more complex.

The only return HTTP status codes I am aware of that explicitly say should not have content include your 3XX codes for redirects and the 204 No Content code.

**Bottom Line**

As Eric Lippert cautions, if you return a body, make sure that the error message you provide does not share information that the user is not authorized to know.  A 404 indicates that there is no resource by that URL.

I work with systems where every call to the core APIs are authenticated, so I know who is making the call, and I am assured of what permissions they have.  That said, I do prefer to have a body that includes a generic error message saying the resource they were looking for could not be found.

Answer (score 1):

HTTP status codes are for machines (software), the response body is for human beings (users). A browser will understand the status code and it will display the body to the user. The user is not expected to know what status code 404 means and the browser will not try to parse the response body.

For a REST API, the question is, of what use would a status body be? Should it be displayed to the user? Should it be understandable by software (e.g. the body is XML or JSON data)? If the answer is no in both cases, of what use would a body be? And if it is of no use, why would you want to include a body?